# AngularJS getting data from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS. What I'm trying to do is to get data from a PHP file that will make requests on a DB and then will display them in a JSON format. For now I'm just testing to see if I can get the data from the PHP and is not working. It displays nothing. In console I get this message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
             at Object.parse (native)
             at cc (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:14:360)
             at Ud.e.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:69:261)
             at http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:69:22
             at r (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:7:290)
             at xc (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:69:4)
             at b (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:70:238)
             at F (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:100:187)
             at http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:101:350
             at k.$eval (http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js:112:68) angular.min.js:92
GET http://localhost/SiteKardinal/includes/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found) angular.min.js.map:1
```

My code is this:

- [test.html](http://pastebin.com/cYQCVWQ0)
- [nume.php](http://pastebin.com/6XKvZfxC)

Comment: use `json_encode` for json encoding.. you forgot about commas..

Comment: Thank you! I will try with the json_encode too.

Comment: It is very simple and always return correct json with unicode and quotes escaping - I write a snippet in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, that previous answer works,
but anyway - change your code to `json_encode` using,
because correct manual encoding is hard to implement
and cause errors very often..

```
$data = array(
  array('name' => 'name1', 'ocupatie' => 'ocupatie1'),
  array('name' => 'name2', 'ocupatie' => 'ocupatie2'),
  array('name' => 'name3', 'ocupatie' => 'ocupatie3'),
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Great! I did it this way and it's just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You miss comma in the JSON you are returning from your PHP script. 
this

```
$out .= '{"name":"name1","ocupatie":"student"}';
$out .= '{"name":"name2","ocupatie":"CEO"}';
$out .= '{"name":"name3","ocupatie":"student"}';
```

change to this

```
$out .= '{"name":"name1","ocupatie":"student"},';
$out .= '{"name":"name2","ocupatie":"CEO"},';
$out .= '{"name":"name3","ocupatie":"student"}';
```